# Can user unselect the value in the spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

If an Android Spinner is not empty, and has a selection, can a user do anything to put the spinner into the "nothing selected" state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a Spinner cannot have such a state. You can however provide an item in your adapter that corresponds to a "no choice" value.